# Using transient factories in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, factory, castle, transient

If you use the `TypedFactoryFacility` in Windsor to generate factories for you based on an interface, the factory itself can be registered as Transient. It turns out that the factory will then release all transient objects that it created when the factory itself is disposed after release.

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(
    Types.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IFactory>().Configure(
        x => x.AsFactory()).LifestyleTransient());
```

This means that if I create the auto-generated factories as transient it neatly allows me to forget about `Release`ing the object created from the factory (as long as I manage the lifetime of the factory itself, of course). The lifetime of such a transient factory would be tied to some other transient object, so when that object gets released, the factory is released, and everything that factory created.

Personally, I hate having to remember to explicitly `Release()` objects, and this cleans up the code a lot, so this makes me very happy. But the question is: Is this reasonable practice? It all just seems too easy.

Is there a downside to creating a new factory instance each time a factory is required?

Am I digging myself a terrible hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic factory mechanism in Castle is based on Castle.DynamicProxy; I imagine that if you use the factory as a transient component you have to pay for the creation of the `ProxyGenerator` at each resolution, unless some other caching mechanism exists.

The [documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy.ashx) warns against recreating the the `ProxyGenerator` each time:

> If you have a long running process (web site, windows service, etc.)
>   and you have to create many dynamic proxies, you should make sure to
>   reuse the same ProxyGenerator instance. If not, be aware that you will
>   then bypass the caching mechanism. Side effects are high CPU usage and
>   constant increase in memory consumption

However it is entirely possible that there is some mechanism that prevents this problem in Windsor, or that the documentation is obsolete.

My recommendation: test with a loop on your transient factory resolution, then resolve your component; keep an eye on memory (also loaded assemblies; maybe the proxied code is loaded in a side assembly) and processor usage to determine whether or not your trick is viable

Comment: Good thought. This was actually one of the things I was concerened about. I did some experimentation, both inspecting the dynamic proxy that gets generated, and running some tests in the debugger...
It looks like the proxy functions are generated only once, so creating and releasing 2 billion factories in a loop doesn't extend the memory usage. It does take about 2 minutes to complete using a whole core, though. I think I can live with this throughput.

Comment: There's only one PG instance kept by Windsor, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: @HamiltonVerissimo Thanks for the info. I didn't have the courage to dig in and check myself, but it sounded logical to use some long lived generator

Comment: Actually if you want more details, Windsor has its own PG that it uses whenever a components needs to be proxied (Interceptors != empty), but facilities like the auto factory will probably create their own.

Answer (score 1):

So the deeper question is related to IDisposable. Why are you using it? Are you really keeping track of unmanaged/limited resources? Are you using it to really dispose something or as a shutdown protocol?

All these will go away if you change Windsor's release policy -- thus making you take care of when/if [to] call dispose. The container is trying to help you by keeping track of what and when to dispose things, but it can only do so much, so sometimes it's better to step up and take over the responsibility.

Another option is to turn off the tracking and expose a service that keeps track of things to dispose. This can be more semantical and understand your business/infrastructure needs.

In sum: what you're doing is fine, but it's not all that common to instantiate a transient factory every time you need the factory to create something. Make sure you document this for the your own future self.

Comment: I'm not implementing disposable on the transient objects created by the factory, although I do want them to be GC'd when they are no longer referenced.
Usually, when you're using a factory to create objects these will be short lived - in my case, they will fall out of scope when the request has finished processing.